# how can I print items in a list one by one

Tags: prolog

I have my answers in a list by findall and the list is called answers.
Now answers can have 0 , 1 or more items.

0 answer I can solve with display_answers([]).

1 answer I can solve with display_answer ([X]).

Can I do more then 1 display_answer([X|X]) and then use foreach to print all the answers ?
Or is there a better way ?

Roelof

Edit1 : 
I tried this:

```
% Displays the output of siblings(X,Y) and takes care that 
% there are no duplicates.
display_siblings(Person) :-
     findall(Person-Y, siblings(Person,Y), Sibs),
     display_the_siblings(Sibs).

% Display a message if there are no siblings found. 
display_the_siblings([]) :-
       write('Er zijn geen zussen/broers bekend').  

% Displays a message if one sibling is found.
display_the_siblings([X-Y]) :-
        write('The enigste broer of zuster is '),
        write(Y).

% Display a message if there are more then 1 siblings found.
display_the_siblings([[X-Y|X-Y]) :-
        write('Alle zusterparen zijn : \n'),
```

But if I use recursion then when Sibs is one then the wrong predicate is used. 
So the question is still what do I take as parameters to make the last predicate work.

Comment: `maplist(print, Answers)` will do

Comment: and then I can make the predicate display_answers(Answers) :- maplist(print,Answers). If so , how can I make the difference between 1 and more answers.

Comment: use a cut after handled patterns: `display_answers([]):-!.`,  `display_answer([X]) :- writeln(X), !.`

Comment: You have a couple of answers below. Are neither of these acceptable? If not, perhaps you could comment on what you are really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My prolog is kinda rusty, but in general you do this with recursion on the list using the [Head|Tail]. Something like:

```
display_answer([]) :- !.
display_answer( [Head|Tail] ) :-
   print( Head ),
   display_answer( Tail ).
```

Hope it helps. Have fun...

Comment: I like this answer but I has one flaw. When I want to do `display_answers([Head/Tail]) :- write("The answers are"), write(Head), display_answer(Tail).` the part of the answers are are also printed several times.

Comment: Are you using a slash [Head/Tail] as in your comment or verical bar [Head|Tail] which is what you should use?

Comment: I use the | . I made a typo sorry.

Comment: Oops, you need a cut in the first clause. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have in my ~/.plrc (the SWI-Prolog basic configuration file on Linux) this definition

```
setln(Pattern, Goal) :-
    setof(Pattern, Goal, List), maplist(writeln, List).
```

that just allows a sorted display of solutions, in case I need it... for instance

```
?- setln(M, current_module(M)).
ansi_term
apply
arithmetic
base32
...
```